# Is it ok to use the intrinsic lock of a Thread object in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

So in Java I know that you can use the so-called "intrinsic lock" of objects to create mutual exclusion regions as well as to ensure memory visibility. Java makes it particularly easy to implicitly lock on the intrinsic lock of the `this` object with some syntax sugar like:

```
public class Foo{
    public synchronized doFoo(){
        //doFoo is executed in an implicit synchronized block
        //on the 'this' object
    }
}
```

This is understandable and accepted practice for guarding the member fields of many objects. What I *don't know* is whether the above is okay when the object being locked on is a `Thread` object. E.g., are there any reasons to avoid the following?

```
public class Bar extends Thread{ //notice the 'extends Thread' here
    public synchronized doBar(){
        //doBar is executed in an implicit synchronized block
        //on the 'this' object
    }
}
```

For now, I'm going to stick with something I know is more safe, e.g.:

```
public class Baz extends Thread{ //notice the 'extends Thread' here
    private final Object explicitLockObject = new Object();

    public doBaz(){
        synchronized(explicitLockObject){
            //doBaz impl
        }
    }
}
```

My concerns would be two-fold with option #2 (the `Bar` example):

1. Is there existing jvm code or Java convention regarding synchronizing *on the Thread itself* that might conflict with such a locking policy?
2. Locking on `this` generally implies that access of that object should always be guarded by that object's intrinsic lock. In the case of a `Bar` thread, that means we're implying that any time you touch a `Bar` thread, you should synchronize on the instance. That seems like it could end up causing some other thread to block unnecessarily (or even dangerously) until `Bar` completes/exits.

Are the above valid concerns? I feel like I need a Brian Goetz beacon for this one :-)

Comment: 1. Well, there is a convention that you shouldn't extend `Thread` in the first place: implement a `Runnable`, pass it to the `Thread` as a constructor parameter (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)). Now, would you be concerned about synchronizing on the `Runnable`?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that convention. To be honest, this isn't originally my code, and I'm not planning to refactor. I know `Runnable` would be fine since it comes with no state baggage. But alas! That's not what I have and I'm curious to know the answer to this.

Comment: I would recommend that developers prefer the new classes in concurrency package and not use raw Threads.  Multi-threaded code is hard enough to write.

Comment: I would avoid synchronizing on a `Thread` object if possible. Or indeed on any publicly visible object. But even more so with `Thread`, as some methods of `Thread` will also use the intrinsic lock themselves.

Comment: Using the intrinsic lock also allows client code to influence the synchronization policy of your object (`synchronized (theBarThreadObj) { … }`). Using an internal `final` object prevents this.

Comment: No it isn't OK, and the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)) specifically says so.

Comment: @EJP: Thanks for the link, but what I see there says "It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances", which I don't think necessarily mean the intrinsic lock is off limits.

Answer (score 2):

> ... are there any reasons to avoid [locking on a `Thread` instance]?

So if you look at the `Thread` class, you can see that there are are a number of instance `synchronized` methods.  They include:

- `start()`
- `stop()` (deprecated)
- `join(long)` (which is called from `join()`)
- `join(long, int)`

> That seems like it could end up causing some other thread to block unnecessarily (or even dangerously) until `Bar` completes/exits.

Right, so anyone calling the above methods would block with other `synchronized` methods.  Obviously only the `join(...)` methods would actual be a problem and they should't return until the `Thread` finishes anyway.

As stated in the [javadocs for `Thread.join(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)):

> As a thread terminates the
>   `this.notifyAll()` method is invoked. It is recommended that
>   applications not use `wait()`, `notify()`, or
>   `notifyAll()` on `Thread` instances.

I see no warnings about `synchronized` anywhere in the `Thread` source.

Also quick glance through `ThreadPoolExecutor` shows that it at least doesn't `synchronize` on the `Runnable` or `Callable` instances which would be pretty bad so at least with a standard `ExecutorService` you should be good.

So I guess the short answer is that although it maybe not recommended, in a pinch synchronizing on the `Thread` should work.  As you mention, it would be better for you to implement `Runnable` and lock on it instead of extend `Thread`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very helpful- I would consider the warnings about `wait()`, `notify()` etc. to be some evidence that using a `Thread` object's multithreading utilities is a little different than using those of any other `Object`, but the lack of a warning about the intrinsic monitor itself does suggest that it _might_ be ok. Upvoted, but I'll leave a few more days for someone to swoop in with some source/argument that definitively addresses the issue rather than relying on lack of a warning (when are docs perfectly complete :-) ?). If nobody jumps in soon, I'll mark as answer.